# Redis not cache all data in ec2 server and data from mongo atlas

Tags: node.js, mongoose, redis

I have used redis but its not work as expected. when first time I have execute the find query results comes from mongoose its give approx 19MB data but after caching redis only one document. don't now where I am doing wrong below share the configuration file.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const  { createClient } = require('redis');
const util = require('util');
let client
(async() => {
  client = createClient();
  await client.connect({
    legacyMode: true
});
 await client.ping();
})();
const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
mongoose.Query.prototype.cache = function (options = { time: 36000 }) {
  this.useCache = true;
  this.time = options.time;
  this.hashKey = JSON.stringify(options.key || this.mongooseCollection.name);
  return this;
};

mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
  if (!this.useCache) {
    return await exec.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  const key = JSON.stringify({
    ...this.getQuery(),
  });
  const cacheValue = await client.get(this.hashKey, key);
  console.log(cacheValue, "Cache Value");
  if (cacheValue) {
    const doc = JSON.parse(cacheValue);
    console.log('Response from Redis',doc, this.model);
    return Array.isArray(doc) ? doc.map((d) => new this.model(d)) : new this.model(doc);
  }
  const result = await exec.apply(this, arguments);
  client.set(this.hashKey, key, JSON.stringify(result));
  client.expire(this.hashKey, this.time);
  return result;
};

module.exports = {
  clearKey(hashKey) {
    client.del(JSON.stringify(hashKey));
  },
};
```

Here is Query

```js
Products.find({is_deleted:false})
    .select(select)
    .populate('type', 'type')
    .populate('shape', 'type')
    .populate('category', 'type is_pain_scale name').sort({updated_at:1}).lean().cache({
      time: 36000
    });
```

Comment: That is an interesting way of implementing cache with mongoose. IIRC `exec` isn't actually called by Mongoose, but is something you need to do yourself (like `collection.find(...).exec()`) to make the query into a real promise. I might be wrong since you are saying that you see something in Redis, but that is where I would start.

Comment: ok I will try this, but redis working but give only one record  thanks